# contract creation code storage out of gas

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

After looking around, I didn't find another question exactly like this, [though 4001 could be related](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/out-of-gas-during-contract-creation) but it was lacking in detail.

I'm trying to deploy a contract on a private chain.  Everything seems fine from the client-side(geth console in this case) and the transaction and receipt show no sign of an issue(that I'm seeing).

```
{
  blockHash: "0x6efd7c9912987a1928548529b6037f36930cbb797c66d60b0bdad4cf0b5f8674",
  blockNumber: 3140,
  contractAddress: "0x87ab8526e28a3e8358ba34aef0c03ef0e2b26ea6",
  cumulativeGasUsed: 191997,
  from: "0x75c4....5638",
  gasUsed: 191997,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0xbc4ac0a19a818b64e37ec4b47e74c8c21125879dd485d3c75a5fa1bc800fb8df",
  to: null,
  transactionHash: "0xe3e69ce4f3de843c748d0e024a8b3359d2168bb225a66e5b09343a17d8c20aaa",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Gas for the deploy transaction was set to `450000`, and according to that receipt, that gas limit was not hit. `solc`'s estimate for construction was `415295` gas and I've tried `500000` gas as well.  That said, I have geth on verbisoity 5 and one of the messages that showed during contract deploy was `contract creation code storage out of gas`.

I dug into geth's code to try and figure out exactly what its problem was.  It [appears to be triggered in `Create`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/evm.go#L288) in the EVM code.  The [maximum size here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/a973d1d5233bbd36cbaed0b7235311d4cd529580/params/protocol_params.go#L63) was set to `24576`(bytes?).  [Perhaps EIP170 is related](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/170) but I'm still not sure how my code could be considered 23KB in any case, so perhaps it isn't related.

The size of the bytecode hex string was 3770.  My constructor sets 2 addresses and a boolean and does nothing else.  So I guess I'm really confused as to what's actually causing this issue.

Could someone explain a bit better about what this error is?  I wasn't able to find much documentation on `MaxCodeSize`.  Maybe it's just late and I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears this really is an out of gas error.  Eventually I made an attempt with 1.5m gas and it completed with 545997 `gasUsed`.  This is a bit problematic in that the transaction receipt shows no sign of error and no exception is thrown.  I only noticed this due to watching geth's stdout with a high verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using hardhat or ethers.js, try to upgrade your libraries to the latest version and try to deploy it again.